# How to get value from list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list_dicts = [{'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 12345, 'Instrument': 'option'},{'Strike': '50', 'Price': 3.95},
{'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 67890, 'Instrument': 'option'},{'Strike': '51', 'Price': 6.19},
{'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 59684, 'Instrument': 'option'},{'Strike': '52', 'Price': 7.58}]
```

To follow up with my dummy data here.

How would I go about finding an option with a `Strike` of `51` and all its corresponding values, i.e, `Price` and `Code`?

Comment: since your list of dict is not uniformed and have different structure you need to loop through it and get the element from it in accordance to your requirements

Comment: It would be better to keep all the details of one user in a single dictionary you would have to iterate over

Comment: @coldy I totally agree I just had to use this simple example as a reference. The real dict is pretty complex.

Comment: FYI, that's a list of dicts, not a dict of lists.

Comment: @chepner noted and fixed thanks

Comment: Why is the data spread between two dictionaries?

Comment: @CameronRosenbaum then it is better to post the real complex dictionary with dummy values

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which dictionary contains which values? If not, why not?

Comment: Everyone I just added my dummy data. Can you please help me on this one seeing as how the data is more concrete now.

Comment: It's still not clear why you have pairs of related dictionaries instead of a single dictionary for each option. You should *fix the process that created the list in the first place*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Literally just modified a some numbers but the data itself is directly from the brokerage.

Answer (score 1):

There's two basic ways to extract information from lists or dictionaries. The first is a simple loop that looks for the item you want. The second is a comprehension that can be far more terse and expressive but not always clear.

In the case where the dictionaries within a list are actually separated (multiple dictionaries make up[ what you would call a single data unit), the loop solution is probably the easiest to undersytand.

Assuming here that there will always be a pair of dictionaries per data unit, of the form you currently have in the question:

```py
list_dicts = [
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 12345, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '50', 'Price': 3.95},
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 67890, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '51', 'Price': 6.19},
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 59684, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '52', 'Price': 7.58}
]
```

A simple solution to find all values of price and code that match a given strike value would be something like (in a complete program so you can play with it):

```py
list_dicts = [
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 12345, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '50', 'Price': 3.95},
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 67890, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '51', 'Price': 6.19},
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 59684, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '52', 'Price': 7.58},
    {'Symbol': 'KO', 'Code': 99999, 'Instrument': 'option'},
        {'Strike': '51', 'Price': 9.99},
]

def getPriceCodeList(strike, db):
    retList = []
    for idx in range(0, len(db), 2):
        if db[idx+1]["Strike"] == strike:
            retList += [(db[idx+1]["Price"], db[idx]["Code"])]
    return retList

print(getPriceCodeList('51', list_dicts))
```

This would return a list of tuples of the data you want, such as for a strike value of `51`:

```py
[(6.19, 67890), (9.99, 99999)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use loops you can just utilize the index of the appropriate dictionary in the list:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {
        'Name': 'John',
        'Surname': 'Johnson'
    }, 
    {
        'Number': 123,
        'Birthday': 1960
    }
]

name = list_of_dicts[0]['Name']
birth_year = list_of_dicts[1]['Birthday']
print(f"{name}'s birth year is {birth_year}")
```

**Output:**

```
John's birth year is 1960
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working with that list (or assuming all other input is formatted that way), you can access by a list index then by a dict index like so:

```
print(dict_list[0]['Name'])  # outputs John
print(dict_list[1]['Birthday'])  # outputs 1960
```

However, like the comments in your answer have said, it would be better to merge all the dicts in the list into one single list, such as `{'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'Johnson', 'Number': 123, 'Birthday': 1960}`, because this way you can access it simply by `dicts['Name']` or `dicts['Birthday']`.

Comment: What if both of my dicts had the same keys, specifically the 'Name'. How would I access that if I were to merge the dicts?

Comment: An option would be to merge the values into a list, resulting in this dict: `{"Name": ["Bob", "Joe"]}`. Other than that, I can't think of any other way.